# can I add a href link with the :before or :after content in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there anyway I can add a href link inside the `:after` of an element with the property `content`. I don't have access to the HTML files.

```
li#uploadMenu:after {
    content: "\2699 \00a0 SUPPORT ";
}
```

Comment: can you use js?

Comment: I don't have the html file. They wanted me to create the CSS file to style the whole site. Now they want me to add the support with the gear icon on top of the right menu next after the add new button. I tried everything but it still don't work. Here is the url of the site https://edutube.hccs.edu/

Comment: Well in my opinion you should ask them, you can't style a website properly if you can't touch their HTML...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content you add with the pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after` don't appear in the DOM. Therefore you can't add HTML with the CSS `content` property.

You can only add text with `content`.